# Simplify large fractions

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

Hi i'm quite new with *Mathematica* and i'm experiencing some problems with `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`.

I'm dealing with a sistem of linear equations:
I have six four-vectors a 4x6 unknown matrix and 6 six-vectors and I'm solving the system in order to recover the matrix elements

```
stokesH = {1, 1, 0, 0};
stokesV = {1, -1, 0, 0};
stokesP = {1, 0, 1, 0};
stokesM = {1, 0, -1, 0};
stokesL = {1, 0, 0, 1};
stokesR = {1, 0, 0, -1};

instrumMatrix = ({
   {a, b, c, d, e, f},
   {g, h, i, j, k, l},
   {m, n, o, p, q, r},
   {s, t, u, v, w, x}
  })


detectH = {ihh, ihv, ihp, ihm, ihl, ihr};
detectV = {ivh, ivv, ivp, ivm, ivl, ivr};
detectP = {iph, ipv, ipp, ipm, ipl, ipr};
detectM = {imh, imv, imp, imm, iml, imr};
detectR = {irh, irv, irp, irm, irl, irr};
detectL = {ilh, ilv, ilp, ilm, ill, ilr};

calibrules = 
  Solve[stokesH == instrumMatrix.detectH && 
    stokesV == instrumMatrix.detectV && 
    stokesM == instrumMatrix.detectM && 
    stokesP == instrumMatrix.detectP && 
    stokesR == instrumMatrix.detectR && 
    stokesL == instrumMatrix.detectL, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, 
    k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x} ];
```

But the expressions of the elements of the matrix are huge (you can find the first element here for example http://pastebin.com/CqBb8akP) and if I try to use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` it uses all my RAM (8GB) and all the swap (circa 10 GB) until it crashes.

As you can see the expression I want simplify is basically a big fraction with only algebraic operations, is there a way to help `Simplify` to do his job?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a system of 24 equations in 24 unknowns and every element is symbolical. One can expect huge results like that then. Perhaps you could try Simplify on each result separately?

Comment: With expr=yourPastBinExpression, expr[[1]]== -1, expr[[2]]==numerator, expr[[3]]== denominator. numerator is a little less than half the size of the whole expression. Simplify[expr[[2]]] or Simplify[Expand[expr[[2]]]] might finish. Then Simplify[expr[[3]]]. Finally reassemble your fraction from the pieces. That won't do all the simplification that it might with the complete fraction, but it may finish and help some. I am able to successfully do things like Expand[expr[[2]]]. You may need to increase TimeConstraint, look that up in the help system to see how to do that.